# How to avoid time being generated after subtracting timedelta

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I have a dataframe which look like this as below

```
Year Birthday OnsetDate
5             2018/1/1
5             2018/2/2
```

now I use the OnsetDate column subtract with the Day column

```
df['Birthday'] = df['OnsetDate'] - pd.to_timedelta(df['Day'], unit='Y')
```

but the outcome of the Birthday column is mixing with time just like below

```
Birthday
2013/12/31 18:54:00
2013/1/30 18:54:00
```

the outcome is just a dummy data, what I focused on this is that the time will cause inaccurate of date after the operation. What is the solution to avoid the time being generated so that I can get accurate data.

Second question, I merge the above dataframe to another data frame.

```
new.update(df)
```

and the 'new' dataframe Birthday column became like this

```
Birthday
1164394440000000000
1165949640000000000
```

so actually caused this and what is the solution?

Comment: What is the type of the `Day` column?

Comment: @JohnGordon sorry, it is a typo... should be Year column and it is in integer form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question, you should know that is not a whole year by using `pd.to_timedelta`. If you print, you can see `1 year = 365 days 05:49:12`.

```
print(pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='Y'))
365 days 05:49:12
```

If you want to avoid the time being generated, you can use `DateOffset`.

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset
df['Year'] = df['Year'].apply(lambda x: DateOffset(years=x))
df['Birthday'] = df['OnsetDate'] - df['Year']
                    Year  OnsetDate   Birthday
0  <DateOffset: years=5> 2018-01-01 2013-01-01
1  <DateOffset: years=5> 2018-02-02 2013-02-02
```

As for the second question is caused by the type of column, you can use `pd.to_datetime` to solve it.

```
new['Birthday'] = pd.to_datetime(new['Birthday'])
```