# Generate Date Ranges in python on yearly basis?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a problem statement in which I want the user to input only month and year :- like "Jan" and "2018" . Now, I want the most optimized way to generate the date range in python for that whole year. I this case I should get list of all dates:-

```
          Date
1   2018-01-01
2   2018-01-02
3   2018-01-03
4   2018-01-04
5   2018-01-05
6   2018-01-06
7   2018-01-07
8   2018-01-08
9   2018-01-09
10  2018-01-10
11  2018-01-11
12  2018-01-12
13  2018-01-13
14  2018-01-14  till 2018-12-31
```

Comment: What is output if `Mar` and `2018` ?

Comment: output will be dates from 2018-03-01 to 2019-02-28 means next whole year starting from 1 day of month and year given.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) with specify start and end datetimes:

```
m = 'Mar'
y = 2019

start = pd.to_datetime(f'{m}{y}', format='%b%Y')
end = pd.to_datetime(f'{m}{y + 1}', format='%b%Y')  - pd.Timedelta('1d')

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range(start, end)})

print (df)
          Date
0   2019-03-01
1   2019-03-02
2   2019-03-03
3   2019-03-04
4   2019-03-05
..         ...
361 2020-02-25
362 2020-02-26
363 2020-02-27
364 2020-02-28
365 2020-02-29

[366 rows x 1 columns]
```

EDIT:

For weekends filter by [`Series.dt.dayofweek`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sofweek.html):

```
df1 = df[df['Date'].dt.dayofweek > 4]
print (df1)
          Date
1   2019-03-02
2   2019-03-03
8   2019-03-09
9   2019-03-10
15  2019-03-16
..         ...
351 2020-02-15
352 2020-02-16
358 2020-02-22
359 2020-02-23
365 2020-02-29

[105 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you also please tell me incase i want to generate only weekday in this list ?

Comment: You can create `end` also by adding a `TimeDelta` of one year: `end = start + pd.Timedelta('1y') - pd.Timedelta('1d')`

Comment: @NilsWerner - yes, but there is problem with leap years, test 2019

Comment: I see, but I don't understand how your solution manages to fix that.

Comment: @NilsWerner - added sample, I think problem is `pd.Timedelta('1y')` added always 365 days

Comment: @jezrael `pd.Timedelta('1y') == pd.Timedelta('365 days 05:49:12')`... what is going on?! o_O

Comment: @NilsWerner - I think it is `'rounded'` general year ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Because using `Timedelta` for very large deltas seems to be imprecise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52196505/how-to-avoid-time-being-generated-after-subtracting-timedelta), you can also use `DateOffset` to perform the date difference calculations:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.tseries.offsets as po

m = 'Mar'
y = 2019

start = pd.to_datetime(f'{m}{y}', format='%b%Y')
end = start + po.DateOffset(years=1) - po.DateOffset(days=1)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range(start, end)})
df
# Date
# 0 2019-03-01
# 1 2019-03-02
# 2 2019-03-03
# 3 2019-03-04
# 4 2019-03-05
# ...   ...
# 361   2020-02-25
# 362   2020-02-26
# 363   2020-02-27
# 364   2020-02-28
# 365   2020-02-29
# 366 rows × 1 columns
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to remove weekends from this list ?

Comment: @ParasGhai - `df1 = df[df['Date'].dt.dayofweek > 4]` solution not working ?

Comment: @ParasGhai please don't change your question in the comment section. Instead, ask the full question from the beginning, or simply create a new question.

Comment: @NilsWerner Okay !!

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following, pandas date_range will do the rest

```py
year = 2019
month="jan"
pd.date_range(f"{year}-{month}-1", f"{year}-{12}-31")
```